# Query function not working beyond column Y

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm using the Query function to pull a list of job names from a different sheet that meet certain criteria. The sheet that has the data that I am pulling the list from has 28 columns. When I try to use Column Z, AA, or AB I get the error saying that Query completed with an empty output. I know this to be false. I've tried playing with the headers and naming the columns like this: Col1,Col2 etc. to no avail. Here is a simplified version of my formula:

=Query('Job Details'!$B$1:$AB,"Select B where AA<95",1)

Why does the query come up with an empty return when I use the above formula when I know that is should not?
This formula works just fine:

=Query('Job Details'!$B$1:$AB,"Select B where I<95",1)

Here's a link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C4NSCOHjaaCrn1Cm03DTTNcepmwzQEU4Lz_9bL-Sp5w/edit?usp=sharing
All personal data has been changed. The problem formula is highlighted green in the "Job est" sheet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
Aaron

Comment: Maybe the AA column has no numeric values less than 95, and there are text values? If you shared your spreadsheet, it would be easier to understand the reason

Comment: @sergey I added a link to the spreadsheet. However I am quite certain that there are numbers less than 95 in that column. I have messed with the formatting of that column even using the "Value" function. Still nothing.

Comment: Column AA has text values of "100", so query takes all values of this column as text. You write text values to this column yourself (see your formulas in this column: `=iferror(IF(... , "100", ...))`). You can correct your formulas and write a numeric value of 100 when the condition is met, not a text value - and I think query will then return the result to you. By the way, you can replace many identical formulas in this column with a single array formula - in this case your table will work faster

Comment: Aahh!! Your right!! I thought it had to do with formating but couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the help!! Also thanks for the thought on the Array formula. I'm trying to speed up the Sheets as much as I can so I'll see if I can figure out how to do that. This whole thing has been a huge learning curve for me but I love it.